# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const addReactions = (message, reactions) => {
    message.react(reactions[0])
    reactions.shift()
    if(reactions.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => addReactions(message, reactions), 750)
    }
}

module.exports = async (client, id, text, reactions = []) => {
  const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id);

  channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
      if(messages.size === 0) {
          //Send a new messages
        channel.send(text).then(message => {
            addReactions(message, reactions)
        })
    }else{
        //Edit the existing message

      }
  })
}
```

So I get this error:

```
PS D:\Raketbot> node index.js
(node:7712) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null
    at module.exports (D:\Raketbot\first-message.js:13:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
etc....
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? This code doesn't look like it's valid for newer versions.

Comment: Put a `catch` in to see what the error is.

Comment: Some explanation and introduction will help us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not receiving the channel object from "await client.channels.fetch(id)".
Verify if you are calling it correctly.